# Setting a cover with MPMediaItemArtwork not working iOS 16

Tags: swiftui, uikit, media-player, avkit

I am building an app with AVKit and MediaPlayer and want to show a cover in the control center. Using this code didn't worked for me:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "myCover") {
                
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
                    return image
        }
}
```

First, I thought that downloading the UI Image failed, but then i realised that this issue also happend when using a locally saved image.

By the way: Setting up the player (pause/play/background mode) worked fine.

I am using iOS 16 and Xcode 14.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is your nowPlayingInfo coming from ?
In my process I declare a new dictionary with titles and stuff
then I process my image later with async download using

```
 MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = artwork
```

I mean if you directly set it in the default Center is it still not showing ?

Comment: I used code from this article to set up my player: https://medium.com/@quangtqag/background-audio-player-sync-control-center-516243c2cdd1